# Laravel Contact us mail form (not sending)

Tags: php, laravel

although i checked every method available on stackoverflow and others i can't get any mail to send at all.
need help fixing it.

mail is configured well and it send other mails like pass reset , verification code which is in same controller ! and all other mails are delivered but the contact form from home page isn't delivering any mails

```
                    <form method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name*">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name*">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email*">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" id="conEmail" value="Send Now">
                </form>
```

the javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#conEmail',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      var email = $('#email').val();
      var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
      var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
      var message = $('#message').val();
      $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       url:'{{ route('contactEmail') }}',
       data:{email:email,firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname, 
 message:message},
       success:function(data){
        swal('success','Successfully Sent Email','success');
        console.log(data);
      },
      error:function (error) {
        var message = JSON.parse(error.responseText);
        swal('error',message.errors.email,'error');
        console.log(message.errors.email);

      }
    });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Route

```
Route::post('/contactEmail', 'FrontController@contactEmail')->name('contactEmail');
```

Controller

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Etemplate;
use App\Frontend;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FrontController extends Controller
{

    public function contactEmail(Request $request)
   {
          $this->validate($request,
        [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required'
        ]);
        $temp = Etemplate::first();

        $to = $temp->esender;
        $name = $request->firstname.' '.$request->lastname;
        $subject = 'User Email';
        $message = 'Email From:'.$request->email.'<br/>'.$request->message;

        send_email($to, $name, $subject, $message);

      return back();  
   }
```

Comment: your route registered as `post` method but you requested the server using `get` method

Comment: I think that you can't use moustache in your url

Answer (score 0):

Just change this - you used get instead of post

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#conEmail',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
          var email = $('#email').val();
          var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
          var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
          var message = $('#message').val();
          $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'{{ route('contactEmail') }}',
           data:{email:email,firstname:firstname, lastname:lastname, 
     message:message},
           success:function(data){
            swal('success','Successfully Sent Email','success');
            console.log(data);
          },
          error:function (error) {
            var message = JSON.parse(error.responseText);
            swal('error',message.errors.email,'error');
            console.log(message.errors.email);

          }
        });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: tried both on get , tried both on post
tried to remove the script and put the route into the form 
tried to change the whole html form 
tried to change the function ! doesn't work for me 
https://span-coin.com if u wanna check

Comment: are you sure you declared the route you are posting to as post in your route file.

Comment: yep, i declared it as post didn't work , i declared it as get it didn't work 
i declared the route and the script both same either way post and get didn't work 
i made them vice versa didn't work 
i checked the front end loading console for errors or any missing element i couldn't find any 
i been looking into that for couple days and i still haven't figured it out !

Comment: yes i tried Mail::($to) i tried Mail::('mail@dom.com', $message);

the rest of the controller file have other mail functions and all using the same method 
send_email($to, $name, $subject, $message);
and they work fine except the contactEmail

Comment: oh i see where the problem is now, you are missing the  {{csrf_field()}}

Comment: since you are posting with, add this to your meta  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>  on the head of your html page and in your script get the token like this  token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content; and pass it with your header  xhttp.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);

Comment: Or if you dont want to go through all the stress, just add your contactEmail route to your middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php

Comment: is it sorted out now?

Comment: nope adding the route to the middleware verify gave error

Comment: Please your route should not be in capital letters, contactEmail should be contactemail. e.g Route::post('/contactemail', 'ContactController@theContactFunction');

Comment: additionally in your middleware/verifycsrftoken.php file, locate this line   protected $except = [
        '/contactemail',
    ]; and add contactemail route to it

Comment: finally in your script change url:'{{ route('contactEmail') }}', to url:'/contactemail'

Comment: i changed the mail value to another mail and it delivered 
laravel won't send back to the same mail address for a reason. 
i tried to send from mail server to itself it delivered but laravel won't do it

Comment: if can upload your codes for me to checkout, I could help out.